# Expression resolves to an unused property

Tags: ios, swift

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "toDetails" {
        if let indexPath = sender as? IndexPath {
            if let nextVC = segue.destination as? JobDetailViewController {
                let valueToPass = jobs[indexPath.row].text <- Thread1
                let passUserName = jobs[indexPath.row].addedByUser
                nextVC.jobDetail.text = valueToPass
                nextVC.userLabel.text = passUserName
            }
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT: I'm now getting "Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value" as an Error.

This is the code of my DestinationVC

```
@IBOutlet weak var jobDetail: RoundLabel!
@IBOutlet weak var userLabel: UILabel!

var valueToPass: String = ""
var passUserName: String!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    jobDetail.text = valueToPass
    userLabel.text = passUserName
}
}
```

Comment: `valueToPass` is `jobs[indexPath.row].text`. What's the meaning of `jobs[indexPath.row].addedByUser` ? You aren't doing `let addedByUser = jobs[indexPath.row].addedByUser`.

Comment: Hint: avoid using `;` in Swift. Put code on its own line and it will be a lot clearer.

Comment: But I'm getting "Extra argument in call" when I call addedByUser in the line            performSegue(withIdentifier: "toDetails", sender: valueToPass, passUserName)

Comment: Why don't you simply do `let valueToPass = jobs[indexPath.row]` ?

Answer (score 2):

> Expression resolves to an unused property

This error means, that you wrote code with reference for some property of some item in `jobs` array, but you haven't done anything with it (declare some constant, change some variable, etc.)

You probably just wanted to declare `Job` item for specific row, so you can do it like this

```
let job = jobs[indexPath.row]
```