# how to call more than one argument

Tags: ios, swift

I try to call two arguments in following code:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let valueToPass = jobs[indexPath.row].text
    let passUserName = jobs[indexPath.row].addedByUser
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "toDetails", sender: valueToPass, passUserName)
}
```

But I get the error "Extra argument in call" 
How can I solve it??

EDIT: I tried following:

```
    let passItems = (valueToPass, passUserName)
     performSegue(withIdentifier: "toDetails", sender: [passItems])
```

But on the following VC the Labels are empty...

Comment: This is essentially a repost of [your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53616890/expression-resolves-to-an-unused-property). What's wrong with the help you received there?

Comment: Because I try to pass the userLabel and the JobLabel separately and in my opinion my last question didn't described of what I try to solve, do you know what I mean? :/

Comment: But the answer shows you what to do. Just pass a Job instance instead of individual fields from the Job instance.

Comment: @rmaddy I have to ask, is this really duplicate?

Comment: @RobertDresler I didn't close close it. But yes, this is since this question is the same as the previous but with the typo fixed.

Comment: @rmaddy yes I know, but I was interested about your opinion since you had wrote your comment "This is essentially a repost...".

Comment: Ok guys, I'm sorry for this, I'm completely new, but could you please help me with this? I've update my question with the new code according to your Answers but it is somehow still not working

Comment: Every time you fix one problem you face a new problem. Your latest issue is answered at https://stackoverflow.com/a/49818897/1226963

Comment: BTW - don't completely redo your question after you have received answers. It negates all of the help you've received.

Comment: sorry but could you explain to me why adding a function which updates the view would be the only way to solve this? I didn't had nil errors like this before when I only passed the job.text

Answer (score 1):

Look, `performSegue` method is declare with these parameters:

```
withIdentifier identifier: String, sender: Any?
```

... so you can't add other parameters.

I suppose you have your custom data model

```
struct Job {
    var text: String
    var addedByUser: Bool
}
```

so for you would be the best, if you're passing the whole `job` as sender.

```
performSegue(withIdentifier: "toDetails", sender: jobs[indexPath.row])
```

then in prepare for segue method you can downcast sender as `Job` and set destination controller's job property

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "toDetails" {
        let destinationVC = segue.destionation as! JobDetailViewController
        destinationVC.job = sender as! Job
    }
}
```

so don't forget to replace `text` and `addedByUser` properties of `JobDetailViewController` by `job`

```
class JobDetailViewController: UIViewController {
    ...
    var job: Job?
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
performSegue(withIdentifier: "toDetails", sender: indexPath)
```

Then, override this method:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {     
    if segue.identifier == "toDetails" {
        if let indexPath = sender as? IndexPath {
            if let nextVC = segue.destination as? DetailsViewController {
                let valueToPass = jobs[indexPath.row].text
                let passUserName = jobs[indexPath.row].addedByUser
                nextVC.text = valueToPass
                nextVC.userName = passUserName
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Note that you should have custom properties .text and .userName inside DestinationViewController.

Comment: I tried it but I get "Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value" as an Error - Yes I got the properties inside my DestinationVC

Comment: I've updated my Question and provided the Code from my DestinationVC